# Cant get bibtex to work

Tags: bibtex

Can somebody help, I can't get my bibtex to work. I've tried reading other similar questions on the site, but I really don't see what I need to do in my case. It looks like I need to run the bib-file, but how do you run a bib-file? 
Furthermore, when I press run in my document where I want my references in, it just comes op with "file not found" and "empty bibliography". Hopefully somebody can help me.

This is my tex-file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{forsog.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{kilde}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

This is my bib-file:

```
@misc{kilde,
address = {New Jersey},
booktitle = {Differential equations :  an introduction to modern methods and applications /},
isbn = {9780471651413},
keywords = {Differential equations},
language = {eng},
publisher = {John Wiley},
title = {Differential equations :  an introduction to modern methods and applications },
}
```

[image: bibtex[![][1]]

[image]

Comment: It seems like you tried to compile your `.bib` file to get the bibliography. This is not needed. Instead compile your `.tex` file with `biber`.

Comment: Also, there is not a single `\cite` command in your `.tex` file.

Comment: Okay. Can you elaborate? I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried also citing, but that dosen't really seem to do any difference.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/134144 shows how to configure texmaker to run `biber`.

Comment: Where are you storing you bib file?

Comment: In my documents, in my Latex folder on my hard drive

Comment: @leandriis I think the question is about biblatex with bibtex although it doesn't appear in the provided code as  a backend option `\usepackage{biblatex}`.

Comment: @Benedikte Toft Would you like to use `bibtex` or `biber` with biblatex?

Comment: @hesham I guess whatever is the easiets. Sorry I'm new in this, so I would really appreciate, if you could guide me through this, it's really stressing me out rn

Comment: @Benedikte Toft Please also copy and paste the contents of your problematic files (bib and tex) to your question here, so that we can easily copy it for debugging.

Comment: @hesham like this?

Comment: Special characters in filenames such as "ø" might cause problems. I would recommend avoiding them.

Comment: Okay, I deleted them, still not working..

Comment: Did you run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex on your `.tex`file? What does "is not working"  mean? Do you get error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is your desired output:
[image]

The tex input would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
%
Some Text.

Cite your file here \cite{kilde}.

\printbibliography
%
\end{document}
```

and the contents of the bib file `reference.bib` (you can change file name, not the extension!) placed at the same directory of the tex file

```
@Book{kilde,
  author    = {John Doe},
  publisher = {John Wiley},
  title     = {Differential equations : an introduction to modern methods and applications},
  year      = {2020},
  address   = {New Jersey},
  isbn      = {9780471651413},
  keywords  = {Differential equations},
  language  = {In English},
}
```

Of course many more comments can be useful for you (e.g. your ref type is not `misc`, it's a `book`; you are also missing the author of ref,..) But at this stage that would do for you. Good luck and welcome to our community.

If you wan to print the bibliography with author family name first, then in tex file add this option `bibstyle=authoryear` to biblatex as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

The result will be:
[image]

There are many other bib styles you can choose from, e.g., `numeric`, `alphabetic`, `authortitle`,.. (you can see more [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles)).

Comment: I recommend you use JabRef (https://www.fosshub.com/JabRef.html) for managing your bibliographies. This will make your life easier when are creating new bib files and ref entries. You can also google other types of bib managers that can do the same job.

Comment: Okay it seems like it's still not working. So just to be sure. I need to make a new document in my texmaker, which I name reference.bib. Here I put the second code you wrote. Then I need to make a document, which is going to be a tex file, right? Here I put in the first code you made. When I then try to run the bib-file, it just yields "Process started

I couldn't open file name `reference.aux'

Process exited with error(s)". The bib file and the tex file is in the same folder on my computer.

Comment: @Benedikte Toft. I added and author and year fields for you in the bib file (you can delete them if you want, but better not and use the correct year and author name). So now start over (copy and past the tex and bib files again. Please DON'T run the bib file. Open the tex file in texmaker and run it from there (Build and View icon)

Comment: Did that, now it just says "Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend", "Citation 'kilde' on page 1 undefined", "Empty bibliography", "There were undefined references", "Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):"... This is such a struggle :((

Comment: Re-run the tex file again after the first run is finished from within (Build and View icon). Don't do anything to bib file.

Comment: Didn't do anything to the bib file. I've tried re-runinng the tex file multiple times from within build and view icon, but the same error messages appear.

Comment: Does your latex system produce pdf file without using citation and biblatex?

Comment: yes it seems like it

Comment: So know I need to run the bib file? Just need to make sure

Comment: [Sorry. Run tex file.] Clean the working directory (delete all files except .tex and .bib ones, i.e. only 2 files remains). Then try run TEX file again, once then twice.

Comment: Okay I did that. Still the same error messages :(( The bib file is supposed to be written in texmaker, and saved there as a bib file right?

Comment: Did you clean before re-running tex file?

Comment: Yes. I deleted everything except the bib and tex file and then I re-ran the tex file two times.

Comment: to create the bib file: 1) create new notepad file name it `reference.txt` 2) copy paste the bib file contents inside 3) save the file and close 4) rename the file to `reference.bib`. Then start over, clean and run.

Comment: Same error messages... :(

Comment: What is the full name of your tex file?

Comment: the name is "nyylitt.tex"

Comment: Can you see a file named nyylitt.log in your working directory? If so please share this file (via dropbox or onedrive links)

Comment: Nope, didn't you say I should delete every file except the bib and tex files? Btw. I'm very grateful that you are using your time helping me!!!

Comment: Yes I said. But after running tex files, you should see some files generated in the working directory. If no, then your latex system isnt executing any build commands, regardless you have a bib or not.

Comment: Please review this video. It may help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI8W4MvFo1M

Comment: After you learn how to successfully compile a simple latex file, you can start trying using biblatex. You are welcome and I wish I could be of more help for you.

Comment: Omg it literally worked now. I changed the settings in the "quick build command" from "PdfLatex+ View pdf" to "pdfLatex+bib(la)tex+pdflatex(x2)+viewpdf". But thanks a lot, I used your code. Very nice of you to spend your time helping me! The references show up now, but it has an error message "Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable." Does that matter?

Comment: Good to hear that. And No it does not matter. That's because you are not using BIBER. But BIBTEX is ok and more compatible for most purposes. Good luck!

Comment: Got it :) Can I btw get the last names to appear first, in the references? Or is it only possible with biber?

Comment: Most things are possible in bibtex. and yes you can make the last names appear first.

Comment: @Benedikte Toft Check the updated answer for your request.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day. But how come the number beside the reference disappear when you use the style where the authors last name is first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105660/discussion-between-hesham-and-benedikte-toft).